# Sn(x) = (x-1)^2n+1/(2n+1)!(n+1) - in C language

Tags: c, numerical-methods

[image]

I tried to use this code to solve the question in the picture but I can't solve it, I'd be happy to help.

how can I fix the code that works for the question in the picture?
thanks.

```
#include

void main() {
    int n, i;
    double sum, x, last;
    do {
        printf("Enter an positive number: ");
        scanf("%d", & n);
    } while (n<0);
    printf("Please enter x: ");
    scanf("%lf", & x);
    sum = last = x;
    for (i = 1; i<= n; i++) {
        last = last * (-1) * ((x * x) / ((2 * i - 1) * (2 * i)));
        sum = sum + last;
    }
    printf("S = %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what the equation is. A Taylor series for something?

Comment: @Galen Looks like it could be Taylor approximations for 2*(cosh(x-1)-1)/(x-1).

Comment: You should be able to derive each term from the previous term, avoiding high powers and factorials. The downside is that the [inaccuracy of floating point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) will propagate.

Comment: Your code has a `* (-1)` which doesn't correspond to the equation, and I don't see anything in the code accounting for the *2, *3, *4, *5, ... (n+1) from the denominators.

Comment: Or is the code the solution to some similar problem, and needs to be modified to match the new formula? If so, do you understand how the code calculates the other formula?

Comment: @WeatherVane The inaccuracy should be rather good here for most inputs, since all the addends have the same sign, and the terms will quickly decrease in magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are using the wrong quotient. Also, a closed expression for the value of the series is available.

From the last term of the formula you can read off the general form of the terms

```
    a[k] = (x-1)^(2k+1) / ( (2k+1)! * (k+1) ),  k = 0,..., n
```

The quotient of two such adjacent terms is

```
    a[k]/a[k-1] = (x-1)^2 / ( (2k+1)*2(k+1) )
```

so that the modified code computing your sum is

```c
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    int n, i;
    double sum, x,x1s last;
    do {
        printf("Enter an positive number: ");
        scanf("%d", & n);
    } while (n<0);
    printf("Please enter x: ");
    scanf("%lf", & x);
    sum = last = x-1;
    x1s = last*last;
    for (i = 1; i<= n; i++) {
        last = last * (x1s / ((2*i+1) * 2 * (i+1)));
        sum = sum + last;
    }
    printf("S = %20.15lf,  S_infty = %20.15lf\n", sum, 2*(cosh(x-1)-1)/(x-1));
}
```